# Jasmine stalling when trying to rake/start?

Tags: javascript, command-line, jasmine

Forgive me if this is the wrong lingo - I'm really new at this, so I'm not even sure how to phrase it or what to look for...this may even be what it's supposed to be doing and I just don't know, haha : /

I'm working on the javascript course on http://testfirst.org/learn_javascript and I'm on a Windows 7 machine. I've installed ruby and jasmine, and I'm working on the first lesson, which tells me to start by typing "rake jasmine"

Typing that into the command line returns the following text:

```
Your tests are here: http://localhost:8888/
[2015-07-24 11:06:11] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-07-24 11:06:11] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-07-24 11:06:11] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7392 port=8888
```

... and that's it. I'm able to open http://localhost:8888 in a web browser and it shows me the tests/specs I need to pass, but the command line seems to freeze after that and I can't enter any other commands... Is there something I'm missing here? Any information at all will be greatly appreciated - like I said, I'm super new at this, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of it is to show you the results of your tests. The library you are using shows them on a web page, but to be able to show a web page you usually need a server.

The command you use `rake jasmine` starts an HTTP server mapped to address `http://localhost:8888/`, it occupies your current terminal(console) session and it will be alive until you close terminal window or use a shortcut to force server shutdown (usually it is `Ctrl+C`). When server is running, terminal window won't actually receive any input from you, it was not designed to, but it will still print log info to the terminal while you use the server (maybe some info about incoming requests). If you want to use your terminal keeping the server running, you should open another terminal window and do stuff in it.

Comment: thank you so so much :) that's really helpful! I figured it might be something that I was just not understanding and I appreciate your patience and kindness!